# Chess game viewer in PSE like Chess SE

Tags: feature-request, questions

I know that not all puzzles on the PSE are that of chess, but I feel that a chess board  viewer, such as that on the Chess Stack Exchange, should be put in for the benefit of us here that do do chess puzzles. My question is this: Why hasn’t it been done yet?

I don’t think that it would be to hard to put it in. As far as I can tell, through logical thinking, that the base code for all of the SE sites must be basically the same, but with slight variations to accommodate the theme for each one. It would save a lot of time, and possiblly money, for the makers of these sites.

All you would have to do is copy and paste the code for the chess viewer from CSE into the code for PSE. It doesn’t seem to difficult to me, considering that the code is already built for you.

I’m well away that I’m probably not using the right terminology and such for describing this, so there’s no need to slaughter me here. Just consider it an analogy to help those uneducated in site making, such as me, to help understand the whole process.

Please do tell me why this hasn’t been done yet. If there is no good reason, I think we must make an effort to put a CSE-like chess viewer into PSE for the benefit of us chess puzzlers and those viewing the chess puzzles.

Comment: Additional reference: [Can we implement a replayer for chess analysis on the site? -- Chess.SE](https://chess.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3). However, the reason why each additional plugin on different SE sites needs to be manually requested with convincing arguments is that [each plugin will increase the pageload on every page request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/128238/241919).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The usual approach to getting something like this implemented is to demonstrate two key things:

1. community agreement that it is wanted
2. questions/answers already exist in meaningful numbers that would benefit from it

The first can be demonstrated by upvoting this question (upvoting a proposal on Meta signals agreement with it).
The second can be demonstrated by compiling a list of relevant posts that would benefit from a chess viewer being directly available. (This could then be used as a list of posts to go edit to use it, should a viewer become available.)

PSE, do we want this?  If so, you (now) know what to do. :)

Comment: Uhh I think a chess viewer is a little extraneous atm, maybe it might be relevant later. I don't think it's worth the trouble though.